# Resetting "HDD Warning???" with Zalman ZM-VE400 external case

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, external-hard-drive, smart

Whenever I turn on (or plug in) the Zalman ZM-VE400 I have, it shows `HDD Warning???`. Sometimes briefly, sometimes until the <kbd>Menu</kbd> button is pressed.

The case contains a SSD drive and as far as I understand the warning relates to the S.M.A.R.T. status of which this drive doesn't support all parts.

How can I reset the warning so I don't receive it every time when turning on the drive?

Firmware reports: `V400_01_040_N`

---

Here's what I have tried so far:

- Unplug and plug back in
- Open the case and remove the SSD, then put it back in
- Press the button on the back side (cover removed) while plugged in
- Press the button on the back side (cover removed) while not plugged in
- `USB Connect` => `Refresh` => <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- `USB Connect` => `Safe Removal` => <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- `Advanced` => `Umount VHDD` => <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: *The case contains a SSD drive and as far as I understand the warning relates to the S.M.A.R.T. status of which this drive doesn't support all parts.* The parts of SMART that it does support ... the drive isn't about to die, is it?

Comment: It says "Health" is "Good", so I'm positive it's not about to die.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been addressed by Zalman. After figuring out [Zalman drive enclosure does not start up (example case ZM-VE400)](https://superuser.com/q/789341/68747), I also ran a firmware update of my ZM-VE400.

Under `Firmware Ver` in the menu the version prior to the update (and with the issue outlined in the question) was `V400_01_040_N`, *after* the update it is now `V400_01_048_N`.

Therefore I can state that firmware version `V400_01_048_N` (N for NTFS) does not exhibit the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The message “HDD Warning???” disappeared after that:
- Set Encryption (Menu -> Encryption -> Set Encryption -> Yes ->  etc...);
- Reset Encryption (Menu -> Encryption -> Reset Encryption -> Yes ->  etc...).

Comment: That is rather unlikely to fix a general problem. And if the base problem really is a broken/breaking disk, this might just mask the error indication.

Comment: @vonbrand: why would you think the disk is broken? The disk simply hasn't got all the SMART values that the enclosure expects and Zalman does not react to support requests. There is no indication that the disk misbehaves when interrogating it with other SMART-capable tools that do not make the mistake of expecting optional values.

Comment: @Pavel: thanks, but won't that in essence destroy the data? The manual clearly states that encrypting the drive (and resetting it later) both are destructive operations.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, zalman warns, what data will be lost. But I have not lost them.
there may be some "features" when working with disks of different manufacturers. Make a copy of data before encrypting.

Take it as an experiment that can succeed or fail. I solved the problem, and again it is not possible to repeat now. In any case, the drive will not spoil it. And back up your data to create better.